# Condition on DataLayer variables inside a macro

Tags: google-tag-manager

On a page I push two custom variables to `DataLayer`, lest call them `Foo` and `Bar`. Lets say `Foo` is a boolean variable and `Bar` is a number.

What I would like to do is for a macro to return `Bar` if `Foo` is `true` and return null\undefined\whatever GA would recognize as not being an actual value when `Foo` is `false`.

Of course I could push another variable that holds the value that I would like the macro to compute, but I would like to know if this can be done using a macro (in other words do it without modifying the page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: It seems to work, so I'm adding the code.

I think I figured it out (writing problems down seems to help solving them). To achieve this, what I need to do is:

- add both `DataLayer` variables as macros (`{{Foo}}` and `{{Bar}}`).
- add a non-standard JS macro that checks the value of `Foo` and returns `Bar` if `Foo` is true

Combined non-standard JS macro looks like this:

```js
function()
{
    if({{Foo}})
    {
        return {{Bar}};
    }
    return null;
}
```

I also assigned default value `false` to `{{Foo}}` macro to avoid problems on some custom pages (like redirect pages etc.).